# Convex hull of bivariate normal random points

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, convexity

Let $n > 1$, and $p_1, \ldots, p_n \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be iid random points following a bivariate normal distribution (doesn't matter which one), and let $X_n$ be the number of vertices of convex hull of $p_1, \ldots, p_n$. By manipulation of integrals we find that $\mathrm{E}X_n = 2\sqrt{\pi} \mathrm{E}M_n$, where $M_n$ is the maximum of $n$ iid standard normal variables (that is, $\mathcal{N}(0, 1^2)$).

**Question**: is there a direct, "elementary" proof of this? I would be happy even with a simple explanation why the two expected values are proportional, without computing the constant (indeed, one can easily find the constant from the case $n = 2$).

To clarify, here I consider using well-known facts (such as explicit form of a normal variable density, or multivariate density symmetries) to fall under "elementary", but not tedious manipulations of integrals and such.

Answer (score 0):

Integral formula (2.13) in [Efron](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2333687) (going back to Renyi and Sulanke) in this case is
$$EX_n=2\sqrt\pi\, n(n-1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\Phi(x)^{n-2}\phi(x)^2, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are the standard normal c.d.f. and p.d.f., respectively.
The proof of this formula is mostly probabilistic, and it is rather short and simple, given the simple but elegant idea due to Renyi and Sulanke, enunciated by Efron at the bottom of the first page of his paper.

On the other hand, $P(M_n\in dx)= dx\, n\Phi(x)^{n-1}\phi(x)$, and hence
$$EM_n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, n\Phi(x)^{n-1}\phi(x)x
=n(n-1) \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\Phi(x)^{n-2}\phi(x)^2, \tag{2}\label{2}$$
by integration by parts.

So, we do get
$$EX_n=2\sqrt\pi\,EM_n \tag{3}\label{3}. $$

Note that the factor $\Phi(x)^{n-2}$ in the integrands in \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} is the probability that all of $n-2$ independent standard normal random variables will take values $<x$ (which is also $P(M_{n-2}<x)$), and this probability appears at the very beginning of the Renyi--Sulanke--Efron argument.

So, to get a "probabilistic meaning" of equality \eqref{3}, it seems enough to understand a "probabilistic meaning" of the second equality in \eqref{2} (if such a meaning exists). In turn, the latter task seems to reduce to understanding of the probabilistic meaning of the equality $\phi'(x)=-x\phi(x)$ (if such a meaning exists) -- which may have to do with [Stein's method (formula (2.3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_method#The_Stein_operator).

Comment: Indeed, this is roughly the same method I used, in absence of a good reference (thanks for these!). The only unintuitive step for me here is the second equality in (2) (the "integration by parts"), it feels like pure formalism. I agree that the ODE seems like a centerpiece of the argument, and that its probabilistic meaning is vague.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov : It it impressive that you recreated the Renyi--Sulanke--Efron argument from the beginning. Did you need it in your work?

Comment: To be honest, my derivation of (1) was not very rigorous, to put it mildly. In a way, RHS of (1) "counts" the expected "number" of right horizontal sides of the convex hull: two points on $x = t$, and $n - 2$ to the left. We can "integrate" it over all possible rotations to find the "number" of all sides. Of course, none of this makes sense since we're integrating "square density". However, this half-baked argument enabled me to notice the proportionality empirically. Looking forward to learn a proper way to reason about this. =)

Comment: "Vertical sides" instead of "horizontal", of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an informal explanation. We use two uncorrelated standard random variables for simplicity:

Instead of counting the vertices of the convex hull, we count the sides.

Instead of counting the sides, we integrate $1/$ their angular widths.

The angular width of the side intersecting the ray at angle $\theta$ is $$\arctan(v/u)-\arctan(y/x)$$
where $(u,v)$ and $(x,y)$ are the points on the hull immediately counter-clockwise and clockwise from that ray. This makes the integral

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(\arctan(v/u)-\theta)+(\theta-\arctan(y/x))}$$

For large $n$, the point $(u,v)$ will usually be the point $p_i$  which goes furthest in the direction $\theta$ among all points in the half-plane going counterclockwise from the ray. Using the invariance of the binormal distribution under rotation, the distance of $p_i$ in the direction $\theta$ is just a maximum of $N(0,1)$'s, and the distance of $p_i$ from the ray is just a positive sample from $N(0,1)$.

So the integral is approximately

$$2\pi\, E\left[\frac{1}{\arctan(|V|/U)+\arctan(|Y|/X)}:U,X\sim M_{n/2};\, V,Y\sim N(0,1)\right]$$

Approximating $\arctan$ by the identity reduces this to
$$2\pi\, E\left[\frac{U}{|V|+|Y|(U/X)}:U,X\sim M_{n/2};\, V,Y\sim N(0,1)\right]$$

But $U/X$ can be approximated as $1$ because the coefficient of variation for $M_{n/2}$ is on the order of $1/\log(n)$. This and the independence of $U,V,X,Y$ together reduce the expression to
$$2\pi\, E\Big[U:U\sim M_{n/2}\Big]E\left[\frac{1}{|V|+|Y|}:V,Y\sim N(0,1)\right].$$
where the expectation on the right is close to $1$. So the overall result is approximately
$$2\pi EM_{n/2}.$$